# How to use relative clauses in a row?

Tags: usage, relative-clauses

I would like to learn how to use two or more relative clauses in a row.

I'll give a few examples

1- The car that I really like that my father gifted me is so expensive.
(The car that I really like and this car gifted to me by my father)

2-) The car that I really like, that my father gifted me, that was manufactured in Italy, that has a strong engine is so expensive.(I know this sentence is unnecessarily long, but I did it on purpose to learn how to use relative clauses in a row)

3-) The car that I really like manufactured in Italy is so expensive / or / The car that I really like, manufactured in Italy is so expensive.

My questions based on the sentences above are

- Are they grammatically correct even if not preferable?
- Is it a correct usage that I used commas with "that" to list relative clauses in a row?
- Which usage is correct in the 3rd example?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your examples are so unlike the way people speak I wonder why you're asking about their grammar. Except in [The House That Jack Built](https://www.pitt.edu/%7Edash/type2035.html) we avoid such constructions. The relative pronoun **that** is not essential if the meaning is clear:
The car my father gave me. The house Jack built.

Briefly, your sentences all need commas. Even **with** commas they're not colloquial.

The car he gave you **was** expensive. (Use the past tense because he has bought it. Or you might say "That type of car IS expensive.)
Sentences like "It's such fun!" and "They're so good!" are exclamations and traditionally take an exclamation mark.
BTW In the UK we say 'gave', not '[gifted](https://www.theatlantic.com/entertainment/archive/2014/12/gifting-is-not-a-verb/383676/)'.

1 The car my father gave me, which I really like, was so expensive!
2 The car I really like - the powerful Italian one my father gave me - was so expensive!
3 The car I really like, which is manufactured in Italy, is so expensive!

Without a comma, *"The car that I really like manufactured in Italy"* implies the same car is also made elsewhere but, in your opinion, less successfully.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for this explanotory answer. I really understood your answer. Why I'm curious about this grammar structure is that I want to learn how to use relative clauses in a row. I will probably not use the structure "The car that I really like manufactured in Italy", however I wonder if a reduced relative clause placed after a normal relative clause can define the first noun even if it doesn't comes just after its antecedent.